# SQLite/Python INSERT OR UPDATE with single statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm doing some batch imports of song data into a sqlite3 database. The raw data contains duplicates (and lots of them), so upon import, I'd like to be able to add a row if the song/artist is not in the database, otherwise increment a `play_count` column.

Is there a way to do this with a single SQLite statement so that I can use `sqlite3`'s `executemany()` function, as opposed to the less efficient method of looping over the data set and doing multiple `execute()` statements?

For example, if I have the following raw song data:

`[('This Song', 'This Artist'), ('Different Song', 'Different Artist')]`

Is there a way to add it to the following table if it doesn't already exist, and increment `play_count` if it does?

```
 song_title   |   artist       | play_count
------------- | -------------- | ----------
This Song     | This Artist    | 1
That Song     | That Artist    | 3
Another Song  | Another Artist | 4
```

The raw data set is very large, and will be done in batches, so I can't do the duplicate handling on the python side.

Comment: Why do you think a loop is less efficient?

Comment: @CL. From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785844/6423848

Comment: You can create a new temporary table, insert your data, and merge it into your permanent tables from there.

Comment: unfortunately sqlite doesn’t have ‘upsert’ stmt: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/UPSERT-td86759.html