# How to insert a CSV file data into MYSQL using Python efficiently?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database

I have a CSV input file with aprox. 4 million records.
The insert is running since +2hours and still has not finished.
The Database is still empty.

Any suggestions on how to to actually insert the values (using `insert into`) and faster, like breaking the insert in chunks?

I'm pretty new to python.

- csv file example

```
43293,cancelled,1,0.0,
1049007,cancelled,1,0.0,
438255,live,1,0.0,classA
1007255,xpto,1,0.0,
```

- python script

```py
def csv_to_DB(xing_csv_input, db_opts):
    print("Inserting csv file {} to database {}".format(xing_csv_input, db_opts['host']))
    conn = pymysql.connect(**db_opts)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        with open(xing_csv_input, newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            for row in csv_data:
                insert_str = "INSERT INTO table_x (ID, desc, desc_version, val, class) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                cur.execute(insert_str, row)
        conn.commit()
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for all the inputs.
As suggested, I tried a counter to insert in batches of 100 and a smaller csv data set (1000 lines). 
The problem now is only 100 records are inserted, although the counter passes 10 x 100 several times.

code change:

```py
def csv_to_DB(xing_csv_input, db_opts):
   print("Inserting csv file {} to database {}".format(xing_csv_input, db_opts['host']))
   conn = pymysql.connect(**db_opts)
   cur = conn.cursor()
   count = 0
   try:
       with open(xing_csv_input, newline='') as csvfile:
           csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
           for row in csv_data:
               count += 1
               print(count)
               insert_str = "INSERT INTO table_x (ID, desc, desc_version, val, class) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

               if count >= 100:
                  cur.execute(insert_str, row)
                  print("count100")
                  conn.commit()
                  count = 0

               if not row:
                  cur.execute(insert_str, row)
                  conn.commit()
   finally:
       conn.close()
```

Comment: The database is empty because it has not reached the `commit()` yet. You could move that into the loop but that will only slow things down further. Perhaps you could introduce a counter and commit every 1000 records?

Comment: Run the code on a small subset of the data to test if it works as intended.

Comment: Is the database in another location over a slow network connection?

Comment: use this method is the fastest method to get csv file into mysql : `LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE MyTable`. my 90 million rows takes about 25 minutes.

Comment: @JonyD At your finally: should you have a final conn.commit() to get the last block of data recorded?  Before you conn.close().

Comment: @Wilson Hauck I think I don't need it there. `finally` will always be executed. If by some error there is nothing to commit, `commit` in `finally` would make no sense. Not sure tough. I'm new in this

Comment: @JonyD You will figure it out.  Good Luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to optimise this insert. Here are some ideas:

1. You have a for loop over the entire dataset. You can do a `commit()` every 100 or so
2. You can [insert many rows into one insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889065/inserting-multiple-rows-in-mysql)
3. you can combine the two and make a multi-row insert every 100 rows on your CSV
4. If python is not a requirement for you can do it directly using MySQL as it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42933107/943138). (If you must do it using python, you can still prepare that statement in python and avoid looping through the file manually).

Examples:

for number 2 in the list, the code will have the following structure:

```py
def csv_to_DB(xing_csv_input, db_opts):
    print("Inserting csv file {} to database {}".format(xing_csv_input, db_opts['host']))
    conn = pymysql.connect(**db_opts)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        with open(xing_csv_input, newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            to_insert = []
            insert_str = "INSERT INTO table_x (ID, desc, desc_version, val, class) VALUES "
            template = '(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
            count = 0
            for row in csv_data:
                count += 1
                to_insert.append(tuple(row))
                if count % 100 == 0:
                    query = insert_str + '\n'.join([template % r for r in to_insert])
                    cur.execute(query)
                    to_insert = []
                    conn.commit()
            query = insert_str + '\n'.join(template % to_insert)
            cur.execute(query)
            conn.commit()
    finally:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: on point 2, I tried but it does not seem possible using it inside the the with `open(xing_csv_input, newline='') as csvfile:` and the `row` in the `for` ( not enough arguments for format string). Does not seem to be able to fill all the values from several rows. Also here says "using parameters does not work well in this case, and it is usually a good idea to execute each statement on its own" - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: For that particular scenario you should look into building one string with many rows [here's a good read on efficient string concatenation](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/). The idea would be to iterate to (say) 100 rows while building one insert SQL statement, and then run that insert followed by a `commit()` call. Does it make sense?

Comment: Makes total sense and it's my goal to make it efficient. Problem is the use of `cur.execute(cmd, args)` where the args are row of a csv reader

Comment: I edited my answer to provide an example of the structure that solution number 2 would have. Again, depending on the number of rows in your file, there might be a better solution.

Comment: the last colum in the CSV file sometimes has values and most of the time has `''` (empty string, as displayed in the csv example). This causes an error in line `query = insert_str + '\n'.join(template % row)` : _"TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"_. I guess because the last `%s` is `''` (or has event no assigned value). Would `"... {}...".format( varX)` be a better solution?

Comment: plus, I think there is a typo in your code. I think it should be `query = insert_str.join(template % (row)).join('\n')` instead of `query = insert_str + '\n'.join(template % row)`

Comment: and there should be a `if count != 0 and `  in the if to skip the first record (when count is 0)

Comment: There were a couple of mistakes in my solution. The `join`  should be applied to the list instead. I don't think there should be any skip. If the statement is `insert_str.join(template % row).join('\n')` I believe the code will simply fail. Have a look at python's [join](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method

Comment: I'm still having problems with the string formatting. I created another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56645469/python-string-formatting-with-percentage-typeerror-not-enough-arguments-for-f) since it's out of scope from this one. I'm accepting your answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: I edited the solution once more, the expression should have iterated over the `to_insert` list. Hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Here. Try this snippet and let me know if it worked using `executemany()`.

```
with open(xing_csv_input, newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_data = tuple(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))
    csv_data = (row for row in csv_data)
    query = "INSERT INTO table_x (ID, desc, desc_version, val, class) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    try:
        cur.executemany(query, csv_data)
        conn.commit()
    except:
        conn.rollback()
```

Comment: thanks but LOAD INTO is not an option here. No file permissions allowed

Comment: Perhaps you should try `executemany()` then. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785844/4626254