# Python string formatting with percentage ("TypeError: not enough arguments for format string")

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code fails to run.

It goes through a CSV file and retrieves the values and formats them in a array of tuples (a insert query) to be used later.
Problem is the csv last column is sometimes a String or nothing (as shown in csv sample below).
The error follows.
Can anyone help me with this?

```py
def csv_to_DB(csv_input):
    with open(csv_input, newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        to_insert = [] # will be list of tuples
        insert_str = "INSERT INTO table (ID, user, user_version, value, description) VALUES "
        template = "('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"

        for row in csv_data:
            to_insert.append(tuple(row)) # convert row/list to tuple and add it to list
            query = insert_str + '\n'.join(template % to_insert)
        #use query for other operations...
```

CSV sample:

```
1,aaa,1,0.0,
2,bbb,1,0.13,
3,ccc,1,0.0,
4,ddd,3,1.0,Rom
5,eee,1,0.08,
```

Error:

```
    query = insert_str + '\n'.join(template % to_insert)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Note: this question is a followup from 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629884/how-to-insert-a-csv-file-data-into-mysql-using-python-efficiently)

**UPDATE**

To clarify: the goal is to create one INSERT with several values instead of several inserts. In this case:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, user, user_version, value, description) VALUES 
('1', 'aaa', '1', '0.0', ''), 
('2', 'bbb', '1', '0.13', ''), 
('3', 'ccc', '1', '0.0', ''), 
('4', 'ddd', '3', '1.0', 'Rom'), 
('5', 'eee', '1', '0.08', '')
```

`to_insert` will be:

```
[('1', 'aaa', '1', '0.0', ''), ('2', 'bbb', '1', '0.13', ''), ('3', 'ccc', '1', '0.0', ''), ('4', 'ddd', '3', '1.0', 'Rom'), ('5', 'eee', '1', '0.08', '')]
```

Comment: Something doesn't add up with that. Either unindent the query assignment or use the tuple(row) inside join function. Your template relates to all lines, or a single line? @JonyD

Comment: @SukumarRdjf I don't think that's the problem since the error is not enough arguments. I believe the error is thrown on the first iteration

Comment: I guess this is the issue. While creating query variable in each iteration, once your `to_insert` variable is not having length of `5`, it throws the error as there are only `5 %s`'s in `template` string. The number of `%s` should be equal to the length of `to_insert` variable.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf that's not entirely accurate, as `to_insert` is a list it is considered as a single argument. no matter it's length. @JonyD could you give an accurate example of the desired output/query?

Comment: What about the `to_insert` variable that you are `appending` to in the previous iteration?

Comment: Try using a list comprehension: `query = insert_str + '\n'.join([template % r for r in to_insert])`

Comment: `r` will be a tuple of 5 elements each time, which will iterate over the buffer in the list `to_insert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to what I wanted. Feel free to use it. It's very fast.
To insert 3,8Million records in a RDS mysql it takes 2 minutes when the `bloc_size=10000`. Thanks to torresmateo

```py
def csv2mysql(csv_input, db_opts, insert_conf, block_size='1000'):
    """
    :param csv_input: the input csv file path
    :param db_opts: is a dictionary. Should be like the following Example:

    tvnow_db_opts = {
        'user': db_conn.login,
        'password': db_conn.password,
        'host': db_conn.host,
        'database': db_conn.schema
    }

    :param insert_conf: see explanation below

    insert_conf = {
        'table_name': 'my_table',
        'columns': 'ID, field1, field2, field3, field_4',
        'values_template': "('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
    }

    table_name: DB table name where data will be inserted
    columns:    columns corresponding to csv; separated by comma. 
                Example: "ID, field1, field2, field3, field_4"

    values_template:  String with following format "('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')". Nr of '%s' must be the same as the nr of fields in the csv/columns in the table

    :param block_size: nr of rows/records to be inserted per sql insert command. Default 1000
    """

    print("Inserting csv file {} to database {}".format(csv_input, db_opts['host']))
    conn = pymysql.connect(**db_opts)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    try:
        with open(csv_input, newline='') as csvfile:
            csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            to_insert = [] # will be list of tuples
            insert_str = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ".format(insert_conf.table_name, insert_conf.columns)
            count = 0

            for row in csv_data:
                count += 1
                to_insert.append(tuple(row))  # convert row/list to tuple and add it to list
                if count % block_size == 0:
                    query = insert_str + ',\n'.join([insert_conf.values_template % r for r in to_insert])
                    cur.execute(query)
                    to_insert = []
                    conn.commit()

            # commit/insert the remaining rows
            if len(to_insert) > 0:
                query = insert_str + ',\n'.join([insert_conf.values_template % r for r in to_insert])
                cur.execute(query)
                conn.commit()
    finally:
        conn.close()
    print('Finished inserting csv file to database')
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired output can be achieved with simple string additions without the need for a string template:

```
def xing_csv_to_crmDB2(csv_input):
    query = ''
    with open(csv_input, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        insert_str = "INSERT INTO table (ID, user, user_version, value, description) VALUES "

        for row in csv_data:
            query += '\n' + str(tuple(row))
        insert_str += query
# do something
```

this produces the following output:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, user, user_version, value, description) VALUES
('1', 'aaa', '1', '0.0', '')
('2', 'bbb', '1', '0.13', '')
('3', 'ccc', '1', '0.0', '')
('4', 'ddd', '3', '1.0', 'Rom')
('5', 'eee', '1', '0.08', '')
```

---

**UPDATE**:
according to @Tomerikoo's idea, an even more simplified version:

```
def xing_csv_to_crmDB2(csv_input):
    with open(csv_input, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        insert_str = "INSERT INTO table (ID, user, user_version, value, description) VALUES "

        for row in csv_data:
            insert_str += '\n' + str(tuple(row))
# do something
```

output is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this expression:

```
(template % to_insert)
```

template is expecting 5 arguments and `to_insert` **will always be 1!** since its a list it is considered as a single argument.

changing `to_insert` to `tuple(to_insert)` and moving the query outside the loop will solve your problem, depends on what you're trying to get.

Try changing your loop to something like this:

```
for row in csv_data:
    to_insert.append(tuple(row)) # convert row/list to tuple and add it to list
query = insert_str + '\n'.join(template % tuple(to_insert))
```

**UPDATE**: according to @JonyD's update, the template is simply not necessary since it forces you to 5 rows. Additionaly, you would want to pass to `join()` the list and not a string. what you should do is:

```
def csv_to_DB(csv_input):
    with open(csv_input, newline='') as csvfile:
        csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        to_insert = [] # will be list of tuples
        insert_str="INSERT INTO table (ID, user, user_version, value, description) VALUES"

        for row in csv_data:
            to_insert.append(tuple(row)) # convert row/list to tuple and add it to list
        query = insert_str + '\n'.join(to_insert)
```

Comment: the `to_insert` is obsolete in this case, isn't it? It was only used to insert the `row` into the `query`... like `for row in csv_data: query = insert_str + '\n'.join(template % tuple(row))`

Comment: @Albo That is true in the case that query should contain one row. It appears the goal is that query will have all data of all rows. a little unclear...

Comment: But now the output won't produce the desired one by @JonyD... a simple string addition would do: ```for row in csv_data: query += '\n' + str(tuple(row))
        insert_str += query```... this will produce one `insert` with all the values afterwards without the need to specify a string template, see my answer

Answer (score -1):

`template = "('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"` - **FIVE** arguments!

But you use:

`1,aaa,1,0.0,` - 4 args (**ERROR**)

`2,bbb,1,0.13,` - 5 args (**OK**)

`3,ccc,1,0.0,` - 4 args (**ERROR**)

`4,ddd,3,1.0,Rom` - 5 args (**OK**)

`5,eee,1,0.08,` - 4 args (**ERROR**)

Comment: The comma in the end of the csv means next field exists but is null. Only row #4 has 5 args

Comment: That's not true since `to_insert` is passed to `template`. `to_insert` is a list so it is always 1 arg.

Comment: But u should set the `None` to template.